# Add an icon to the scenes with react-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-router

Add an icon to the scenes with react-router-flux, I'm trying to use the leftButtonImage property but I'm not able to allocate an image to the button.  [Something like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOPXY.png)

```
<Scene
  onLeft={() => Actions.Menu ()}
  leftButtonImage='https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'
  key="employeeList"
  component={Home}
  title="LOGO"
  initial
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md#navigation-bar-left-button) you have to use the same kind of object that you would pass to the [`source` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#source) in an `<Image/>`. Your code should look like this:

```
<Scene
  onLeft={() => Actions.Menu ()}
  leftButtonImage={{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
  key="employeeList"
  component={Home}
  title="LOGO"
  initial
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stack tag from react-native-router-flux and use icon property

```
<Stack
      key="home"
      title= "My Title at nav bar"
      icon={() => <Icon size={24} name="home" /> 
      text="Home"
     >
      <Scene
            onLeft={() => Actions.Menu ()}
            leftButtonImage='https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'
            key="employeeList"
            component={Home}
            title="LOGO"
            initial
            />
    </Stack>
```